# I need HELP getting the ALL Report choice in the drop down to run the Report for ALL

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, dataset, drop-down-menu

I'm pulling from Table A which has 4 Transaction Statuses... '03', '05', '06', & '07'
I've defined a dataset which pulls them...

```
SELECT 'ALL' AS label, NULL AS value, 0 AS iordr
UNION ALL
SELECT '03' AS label, '03' AS value, 1 AS iordr
UNION ALL    
SELECT '05' AS label, '05' AS value, 2 AS iordr
UNION ALL
SELECT '06' AS label, '06' AS value, 3 AS iordr
UNION ALL
SELECT '07' AS label, '07' AS value, 4 AS iordr
ORDER BY iordr
```

But when I try to define the Parameter, when I select ALL from the drop down of the report, it doesn't pull '03', '05', '06' and '07' - in fact, it pulls NOTHING... how do I make it so that the 'ALL' choice will pull ALL statuses in one report?
Report Parameter Properties:

**General**

Data Type: Text; Allow null Value
Select parameter visibility: Visible
**Available Values:**
Select from one of the following options:
Get values from a query
Dataset (the one defined above)
Value field: value
Label field: label
**Default Values:**
Select from one of the following options: No default value

Comment: What reporting tool are you using?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta From the details of the Report Parameter properties, looks like SSRS. (I retagged.)

Comment: Do you have another dataset which pulls the data for your report? (You should.) Can you share how that uses the parameter? This is probably the problem.

Comment: Will that `ORDER BY` apply to the entire dataset, or just for `07`?  DB2 requires the use of a dummy table, so it would only apply to the last one there, but I'm not sure in this instance.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 - I thought my query created another column iordr - and it's that column that is ordered sequentially... 0, 3, 5, 6, 7 - the dropdown in my report shows ALL, 3, 5, 6, 7 - and when I choose ALL, the report that runs shows nothing so I'm missing something that is pulling together all the statuses and running the report on all the statuses and thus returning ALL the information from the original table.

Answer (score 0):

The value selected from your dropdown will be one of `{ NULL, '03', '05', '06', '07' }`. So you can write your `WHERE` clause in the report like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE SomeColumn = @UserSelectedValue
  OR @UserSelectedValue IS NULL
;
```

It won't work if your `WHERE` clause is just `WHERE SomeColumn = @UserSelectedValue` because `= NULL` is not valid (as ANSI-standard anyway), and it would only give you results for `SomeColumn` being `NULL`.

By effectively comparing `NULL IS NULL` you're creating a condition that holds for every single row, and thus gives you **all** the data.

Comment: I am designing my RDL in Microsoft Visual Studio (SSRS 2008).<br>I have an original table... and then I've created a data source (dt) where I'm pulling the transaction_status - and it's the transaction_status that I am interested in pulling the data for my report.  The parameter is setup to display the choices in the drop down menu in the report...

Comment: Right. So you can get the underlying query for your report and edit the `WHERE` clause to be similar to what I've posted. It will change according to your table definition, but the concept still applies.

Comment: the underlying query for my report... is that my Parameter or my dataset from which the parameter is pulling its information?

Comment: How would I include what you've indicated above? I'm assuming the what you've provided would somehow go along with the first part of my query? Meaning --Select "all' as label, NULL as value, 0 as iordr -- how would I add in the WHERE part of the statement that you've provided?

Comment: Your first query is used to generate the values for the dropdown list. The query I gave includes part of a `WHERE` clause that would be used in the SQL that generates your data set.

Comment: I'm obviousely learning and I apologize for being SO stupid... but I am lost.  I've setup a view... a procedure... a dataset which drives my parameter... a parameter... and I still don't know where to include the WHERE statement you've provided... suggestion?  How exactly would it be written?

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS, multi-value parameters are passed to SQL as a comma separated string.

The easiest way to use a SSRS multi-value parameter is to have the full SQL query embedded in a dataset, and use the form `WHERE myTable.Column IN ( @MyParameterName )`

Or you can move your filtering parameter into the dataset filter or maybe a filter on the tablix that you are using.

If you really need to pass the multi-value parameter in to a stored procedure, then you will need to do a little bit of string parsing to split it at the appropriate commas.